# JavaScript array inside an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to put an array on "locationsList". The example below outputs

```
"['Location 1', 'Location 2', 'Location 3']"
```

with brackets and everything.

What am I missing?

```
App.controller('locationAccordionCtrl', function ($scope) {

  $scope.locations = [
    {
      "siteName":"First Site",
      "siteID":"First ID",
      "locationCount":"200 Locations",
      "locationsList":['Location 1', 'Location 2', 'Location 3'],
      "open":false
    }
  ];

});
```

This is what my HTML looks like:

code:

```
<div ng-controller="locationAccordionCtrl">
    {{location.locationsList}}
</div>
```

visual:

```
200 Locations 
['Location 1', 'Location 2', 'Location 3']
```

What I want is it to list out all locations (with line breaks).
EG:

```
200 Locations 
Location 1
Location 2
Location 3
```

Comment: What's your "output" code?

Comment: If it outputs the entire array, the problem is with the code that does the outputting. Show the view too.

Comment: So you have an array that contains one objects as its only array member. This object has several properties, one of which has an array assigned as a value to it. This was clear for you?

Comment: To access the array member inside locationsList, you'll have to go with the usual syntax: $scope.locations[0].locationsList[0] will for example give you "Location 1".

Comment: Are you putting `{{locations.locationsList}}` somewhere in your view and expecting something other than the string representation of the array? If you want to iterate the values & build a part of your DOM from each (e.g. a `<ul><li>Location 1</li>...</ul>`) use [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat). If you're trying to construct a string without the brackets, use `{{locations.locationsList.join(', ')}}`. If it's something else, please provide more information.

Comment: I think your example is still missing a piece. I'm assuming you already have an `ng-repeat="location in locations"` somewhere, for you to be able to do `{{location.locationsList}}` and get any output. If so, can you please include it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your HTML looks something like this:

```
<html>
  ...
  <div ng-controller="locationAccordionController">
  </div>
  ...
</html>
```

To get the output you're looking for, you need to use [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) to iterate over your array and construct a DOM element for each (e.g. a `<li>`):

```
<html>
  ...
  <div ng-controller="locationAccordionController">
    <div ng-repeat="location in locations">
      <p>{{location.locationCount}}</p>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="innerLocation in location.locationsList track by $index">
          {{innerLocation}}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  ...
</html>
```

**UPDATE:** Note the `track by $index`; this is because Angular needs a way to link those created DOM elements to the model in `$scope`, and if you have duplicate strings in your array, Angular (or JavaScript in general) can't tell them apart. Therefore, we use the position in the array (`$index`) as the unique identifier of each element, in case there are duplicates.

You can style the list-items so that they don't have bullets (e.g. [`list-unstyled`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#unstyled) if you're using Bootstrap), or you can just make them `<p>`s instead of a list.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I was not understanding how to access the nested locationList.

Comment: No problem @simple. I updated my answer to include `track by $index` and explained why. It's a good practice, when you're iterating over primitives & there's the possibility of duplicate values in the array (even if there's not such a possibility, it doesn't hurt).

Comment: I have multiple locationsList in my locations object. How do I get my innerLocation to "index" for only each instance?

Comment: Can you update your question with a more complete example of `$scope.locations`, which also shows what you mean by multiple `locationsList`?

Comment: I created another question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31149507/find-sibling-of-current-array-item

Answer (score 0):

What I feel is you are trying to paint

```
{{locations.locationsList}}
```

locationsList is an array and to paint then individually you need to use **ng-repeat**

```
<div ng-repeat="location in locations.locationsList">{{location}}</div>
```

For reference - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Answer (score -2):

Actually you have that nested array correct.

Use chrome F-12 go to console and copy + paste and you'll see you did it correctly:

My example:
foobar = { something: "else", "foobar" : "yes", "delta" : ["hello", "world"]}

Perhaps your issue is with the callback in jquery

Comment: Do NOT use quotes around the nested array.

Comment: The OP never mentioned jquery. This is an angular question and in all likelihood, the OP is just putting `{{locations.locationsList}}` in their view and expecting something other than a string output.