# Find sibling of current array item

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This currently lists out all occurrences of the array. I only want to show the array associated for the current item in the parent array.

EG: Instead of listing First Location, Second Location, Third Location. I want it to only list First Location for the First Location, Second Location for the Second Location, etc. What am I missing?

http://plnkr.co/edit/ilgOZzIy2axSi5Iy85C7

```
var App = angular.module('App', []);

App.controller('locationAccordionCtrl', function ($scope) {

  $scope.locations = [
    {
      "siteName":"First Location",
      "locationsList":['First Location 1', 'First Location 2', 'First Location 3']
    },
    {
      "siteName":"Second Location",
      "locationsList":['Second Location 1', 'Second Location 2', 'Second Location 3']
    },
    {
      "siteName":"Third Location",
      "locationsList":['Third Location 1', 'Third Location 2', 'Third Location 3']
    }
  ];
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="locationAccordionCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="location in locations">

      {{location.siteName}}

      <div ng-repeat="location in locations">
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="listOfLocations in location.locationsList track by $index">
            {{listOfLocations}}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div><!-- /row -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change:

```
<div ng-repeat="location in locations">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="listOfLocations in location.locationsList track by $index">
            {{listOfLocations}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

To this:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="listOfLocations in location.locationsList track by $index">
        {{listOfLocations}}
    </li>
</ul>
```